# Huffman code in binary(java)?

Tags: java, huffman-code

I have successfully built my Huffman tree and I have a method that traverses the the tree and saves the Huffman code for each character as a String of 1s and 0s:

```
    public void encode(HuffmanNode node, String aux) {

    if (!node.isLeaf()) {
        if (node.getLeft() != null) {
            aux = aux + "0";
            encode(node.getLeft(), aux);
        }
        if (node.getRight() != null){
            aux = aux + "1";
            encode(node.getRight(), aux);
        }
    } else {
        //building a character-code pair and add to keyMap
        keyMap.put(new Character(node.getCh()), aux);
    }
}
```

where keyMap is a HashMap that maps each character to its Huffman-code.

However, saving Huffman-codes as Strings only increases the size of the encoded file instead of compressing it, since you need a String of 0s and 1s to represent a single character. So is there a way to save the code as binary bits instead of String? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `String` to store the binary result, use a `java.util.BitSet`.

It does exactly what you want, allowing you to set individual bits by index position.

When you are ready to extract the value in binary you can use `toByteArray()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. I tried BitSet and it worked really well. One problem though is that BitSet doubles its size as it's being filled up, but there is not enough characters to fill up the extra bits, so I always end up with a line of unwanted text at the end when decompressing. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Keep track of how many bits you actually use, round up to 8 and then take only that many bytes from the byte array.  You should also include the length of the uncompressed message as a prefix to the data stream so the decompressor can know when the full message has been decompressed.